# Is there a way to wrap one or more tests in a group within the test interface?

Tags: origen-sdk

We are dynamically creating bunches of characterization tests within our test interface.  I would like to enclose them in a group for readability.  I see that [groups can be referenced in the flow files](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/flowapi/#Conditions_Applied_to_Groups), is there an 'start_group' interface method where a list of tests could be added to as they are created?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can assign a group parameter to individual tests, which might help:

```ruby
group :my_group do
   test :test1

   test :test2
end

# This is equivalent
test :test1, group: :my_group
test :test2, group: :my_group
```

Obviously the group parameter could be injected within the interface if that is preferable in your case.

Also remember that everything you can call in a flow you can call in an interface, so you could also use the `group :blah do ... end` approach within your interface logic.

Comment: thx @ginty, it worked as expected.  One other question: can the flow ATP be queried to see if a group already exists?

Comment: No, generally nothing is stored in a lookup table during the test program generation process. A method to create and return one would need to be added similar to this PR - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/atp/pull/9